# How to print python Pint quantities and its meaning

Tags: python, pint

I am very new to python and python pint. I just want to know the supportable units of python pint.
Also what is the meaning of the below representation:

```
{length: 1, time: -1}
```

Reference from  [pint unit](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developers_reference.html#pint-unit). Also how do I print the available pint units for energy and temperature.

```
from pint import UnitRegistry
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
ureg.Unit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys of the dictionary are the dimensions, and the corresponding value is the power of that dimension. That is, `{length: 1, time: -1}` is the representation of velocity, and an example of a unit whose dimensionality is represented by the dictionary would be m/s. For acceleration, the representation would be `{length: 1, time: -2}`:

```py
In [13]: ureg.Unit('m/s').dimensionality
Out[13]: <UnitsContainer({'[length]': 1, '[time]': -1})>

In [14]: ureg.Unit('m/s^2').dimensionality
Out[14]: <UnitsContainer({'[length]': 1, '[time]': -2})>
```

To get available units of a given dimensionality, use `UnitRegistry.get_compatible_units`; for instance, for your two examples:

```py
In [9]: ureg.get_compatible_units('[energy]')
Out[9]:
frozenset({<Unit('electron_volt')>,
           <Unit('rydberg')>,
           <Unit('hartree')>,
           <Unit('erg')>,
           <Unit('joule')>,
           <Unit('foot_pound')>,
           <Unit('calorie')>,
           <Unit('fifteen_degree_calorie')>,
           <Unit('international_calorie')>,
           <Unit('atmosphere_liter')>,
           <Unit('thermochemical_british_thermal_unit')>,
           <Unit('international_british_thermal_unit')>,
           <Unit('british_thermal_unit')>,
           <Unit('watt_hour')>,
           <Unit('US_therm')>,
           <Unit('therm')>,
           <Unit('ton_TNT')>,
           <Unit('tonne_of_oil_equivalent')>,
           <Unit('quadrillion_Btu')>})

In [10]: ureg.get_compatible_units('[temperature]')
Out[10]:
frozenset({<Unit('degree_Rankine')>,
           <Unit('kelvin')>,
           <Unit('degree_Fahrenheit')>,
           <Unit('degree_Reaumur')>,
           <Unit('degree_Celsius')>,
           <Unit('atomic_unit_of_temperature')>,
           <Unit('planck_temperature')>})
```